# Prove recurrence T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/lgn is O(nlglgn) using Substitution Method

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

Prove that $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + \frac{n}{\log_2n}$ is $O(n\log_2\log_2n)$, where $T(1) = Θ(1)$.

I tried to form the Induction Hypothesis but didn't succeed in choosing the right one.

*Try 1:*

If we assume $0 ≤ ck\log_2\log_2k,\forall k < n$, must show $T(n) ≤ cn\log_2\log_2n$.

$$ T(\frac{n}{2}) ≤ c(\frac{n}{2})\log_2(\log_2n - 1),\because \frac{n}{2} = k < n$$
\begin{align}
& T(n) ≤ cn\log_2(\log_2n - 1) + \frac{n}{\log_2n}\\
& ≤ cn\log_2\log_2n + \frac{n}{\log_2n}\\
\end{align}
but this expression is never less than $cn\log_2\log_2n$, due to the positive $\frac{n}{\log_2n}$ term.

*Try 2:*

Assume $0 ≤ ck\log_2\log_2k - \frac{bk}{\log_2k}, \forall k < n$, must show $T(n) ≤ cn\log_2\log_2n - \frac{bn}{\log_2n}$.

$$T(\frac{n}{2}) ≤ c(\frac{n}{2})\log_2(\log_2n - 1) - \frac{bn}{2(\log_2n - 1)}, \because \frac{n}{2} = k < n$$
\begin{align}
& T(n) ≤ cn\log_2(\log_2n - 1) - \frac{bn}{(\log_2n - 1)} + \frac{n}{\log_2n}\\
& ≤ cn\log_2\log_2n - \frac{bn}{\log_2n} + \frac{n}{\log_2n}\\
\end{align}
If we factor the $\frac{-n}{\log_2n}$ out, we get $cn\log_2\log_2n - \frac{n}{\log_2n}(b - 1)$. Once again, it's never less than $cn\log_2\log_2n - \frac{bn}{\log_2n}$ because its $\frac{n}{\log_2n}$ negative factor is bigger.

I tried reforming the inductive hypothesis to be $ck\log_2\log_2k - \frac{2bk}{\log_2k}$, $ck\log_2\log_2k - \frac{bk}{2\log_2k}$, $ck\log_2\log_2k + \frac{bk}{\log_2k}$, but I can never get my expression bounded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(n) = T(n)/n$, so that
$$
S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{n} = \frac{2T(n/2)}{n} + \frac{1}{\log_2 n} = S(n/2) + \frac{1}{\log_2 n}.
$$
Suppose now that $n = 2^k$, and suppose $S(1) = T(1) = C$. Then
$$
S(2^k) = S(2^{k-1}) + \frac{1}{k},
$$
and so unrolling, we get
$$
S(2^k) = \frac{1}{k} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\ell} + S(2^{\ell-1}).
$$
In particular, taking $\ell = 1$, this gives
$$
S(2^k) = \frac{1}{k} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1} + S(1) = H_k + C,
$$
where $H_k$ is the harmonic number, well-known to satisfy $H_k = \ln k + O(1)$. Therefore if $n = 2^k$ then
$$
T(n) = nS(n) = n\ln\log_2 n + O(n).
$$
Using more accurate asymptotics of the harmonic number, we can find an even better approximation to $T(n)$, for example
$$
T(n) = n\ln\log_2 n + (\gamma+C) n + \frac{1}{2} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

Comment: sorry for not being able to handle this given your hint. as I understood if I prove that $S(n)$ is $O(\log_2\log_2n)$, then $T(n)$ is $O(n\log_2\log_2n)$. but while trying to prove $S(n)$, I face the same problem of not being able to get rid of the fraction positive term. So far I've only seen the non-recurrent part as some standard functions, I searched the internet and never found one with a fraction instead. Also, if only $T(n/2)$'s factor was bigger than 2, I could've worked more with terms. Can you maybe give me links to similar problems or give another tiny hint?

Comment: I’m sorry, but you’ll have to take it from here. Don’t try to plug anything into formulas. Take the recurrence as your starting point, and try to evaluate it *exactly*.

Comment: assuming $S(n) ≤ c\log_2\log_2k$, $S(n) = c\log_2(\log_2n - 1) + \frac{1}{\log_2n} = c\log_2(\log_2n(1 - \frac{1}{\log_2n})) + \frac{1}{\log_2n} = c\log_2\log_2n + c\log_2(1 - \frac{1}{\log_2n})+ \frac{1}{\log_2n} ≤ c\log_2\log_2n + \frac{1}{\log_2n} - \frac{c}{\log_2n} ≤ c\log_2\log_2n$, as long as $c > 0$. Take $c = 1$, then $S(n) = O(\log_2\log_2n)$